# Get element parent height inside directive in AnguarJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do you get and set the parent height from an element from inside a directive?

This is what I have now, obviously it's not working.

```
var vAlign = angular.module("vAlign", [])
.directive('vAlign', function() {
  return {
        restrict : "AC",
        link: function(scope, e){

            e.parent.height(1200);
            console.log(e.parent.height);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `parent` and `height` methods of jqLite/jQuery:

```
link: function(scope, e) {
    e.parent().height(1200);
    console.log(e.parent().height());
}
```

Or you could do it in pure javascript with `parentNode` property, which is a reference to parent element:

```
link: function(scope, e) {
    e[0].parentNode.style.height = 1200 + 'px';
}
```

Also note, that since `e` is an jqLite/jQuery instance here which is a array-like collection of one single element, you need to use `[0]` to access raw HTMLElement.

Comment: Ah oke great. Many thanks it works now!
It seems I just needed to add the parenthesis..

Answer (score 5):

e.parent is a function, so you must call it as such:

```
e.parent().height(1200);
```

Further, if you do not load jquery on the page, you will have to use

```
.css('height', '1200px')
```

instead, as jqLite does not include .height